# Asp.net mvc3:How to put username info in the Layour=t file

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking to display the current username logged in the header in the layout file.  What is the best way to accomplish this? I am not currently passing any model into the layout file.  Also, if noone is logged in, I don't want to display a username obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on the `_LogOnPartial.cshtml` view on the default template!

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```